# How to generate standard normal random variable with $Z>-1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, numerical-methods, normal-distribution

Assume that we have a continuous uniform random number generator on $(0, 1)$.

It is well-known that rejection-acceptance sampling can be used to generate standard normal random variable $Z$ by comparing standard normal density function with exponential density function, where the latter can be generated through inverse sampling transform (the inverse CDF of exponential distribution has a closed form).

However, suppose that we impose certain condition on $Z$, say $Z>-1$. How can one generate random samples that fulfill this condition?

Comment: Keep rejecting until $Z>-1$, and then accept, is one way.

Comment: Inverse transform sampling can also be directly applied to quantile function of truncated normal distribution since its easy to compute.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @Aaron Hendrickson nice find! Perhaps you can put it as an andeer by elaborating a bit?

Comment: If you're not limited to any particular method then I would just use the Box-Muller transform. Just discard samples that are less than -1.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yes, I am aware of the Box-Muller transform to generate a pair of independent standard normal random variables.